# How to x and y range the same in log scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
f=data.frame(x=exp(rnorm(100)), y=exp(rnorm(100, sd=2)))
ggplot(f, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + coord_fixed() + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```

The ranges of x and y are not the same. How can I make the ranges be the same for x and y while showing all the points?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `limits` in both of your log scales like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
f=data.frame(x=exp(rnorm(100)), y=exp(rnorm(100, sd=2)))
ggplot(f, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + coord_fixed() + 
  scale_x_log10(limits = c(0.1, 10)) + 
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(0.1, 10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't want to manually set the limits. Is there an automatical way to let ggplot2 determine the same range to set for x and y?

Comment: Hi @user1424739, I don't think it is possible to do this automatically because it depends on your data. An option might be to use the min and max value of your x or y values and set these as limits.